# Pandas_GBQ query receiving 504 error from BQ

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am reading a table [200,000 rows; 40 columns] from BigQuery in a Flask application (using the Pandas GBQ library); the goal is to display some summary data as HTML tables in the UI.

An upstream server is returning a 504 (gateway timeout) error response when I attempt to read this table from my Flask function, however it is successful when running my cloud console.

I have tried reading chunksizes, however this has not solved the issue.

```
project_id = "<projectid>"

bq_table = request.form.get('bq_table')
query = "SELECT * FROM `<dataset>.{bq_table}`;".format(bq_table=bq_table)
df = pd.DataFrame(pq.read_gbq(query, project_id, dialect='standard'))
```

I am expecting the query to run synchronously (not ideal, I know, but this is for an ad-hoc DQ tool).

Comment: If you must run synchronously then probably you'll have to set `timeout` parameters for your web server (either nginx or gunicorn or both): https://serverfault.com/questions/490101/how-to-resolve-the-gunicorn-critical-worker-timeout-error
Still, I'd recommend testing google [datastudio](https://datastudio.google.com/) which does exactly the same with lots of features and designs.

Comment: Running Synchronously isn't a requirement, just keeps the development simpler.  If this issue could be resolved (potentially) by running async, I'm all for it, would just have to brush up on my multithreading & front-end!